# How to open grep(1p) manpage?

Tags: grep, man, posix

At the end of `man grep`, it says

```
SEE ALSO\ 
   POSIX Programmer's Manual Page
       grep(1p).
```

I am not able to open the manpage `grep(1p)`. How do I do that? Search net, Unix.SE and did trial and error but no luck yet.

Tried

```
$ man 1p grep
$ man -K grep
```

EDIT:

I am on Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: What platform are you using?  Does it have the POSIX man pages installed?  If you're on Ubuntu you may need to install the `manpages-posix-dev` package.

Comment: @EricRenouf Do you know how to install these on OSX? Dropping the files in /usr/local/share/man doesn't work.

Comment: If you're not averse to using an online manpage: `http://manpages.ubuntu.com/grep.1p` should take you to the POSIX `grep` manpage.

Comment: @Random832 I found a page at the Apple SE that says it has instructions: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87863/where-are-the-posix-message-functions-msgsnd-msgrcv-etc-man-pages-in-mac that says you can put the files in `/usr/local/share/man/manX` for suitable X

Comment: @EricRenouf This makes it use them instead of the system manpages.

Answer (score 10):

`1P` is an extension to `1` man page of grep. You can use `man -e P grep` to get `P` extension manual page(`man -e 1p grep` should also work).

There is also other way: `man -a grep` shows all man pages for `grep`, so you can skip unnecessary pages manually, and go to 1P.

You also may want to learn how to use man - `man man` will get you there(yes, `man` has its own man page).

edit: In case you don't have mentioned man pages, if you're using Ubuntu or Debian, you might want to install `manpages-posix-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-posix-dev
```

Comment: When would `man -e P grep` work while `man 1p grep` does not work?

Comment: @EricRenouf Sections only have numbers. The pages in "p" are "extension p to section 1", not "section 1p". `man 1p grep` is trying to find "section 1p" which doesn't exist. Either `man` ignores the `1p` completely, or  interprets it as `1`, but either way the first thing it finds is `man 1 grep`. `man -e p grep` searches through *all* the sections in the usual order, looking for pages with extension p, and the first one it finds (and displays) is in section 1 extension p. `man -e p 1 grep` specifies exactly which page you want to display.

Comment: @alephzero `man 1p grep` works perfectly for me (is it a gnu extension?). I guess the difference lies in the version of man.

Comment: @alephzero I don't think you're quite right about that.  From `man man` there are more sections than those (of which 1p is an example for Red Hat type systems at least): `Distributions  customize  the  manual section to their specifics, which often include additional sections.` so there is not a requirement that sections are only 1 through 8, and 1p definitely does exist on some systems at least (Fedora and CentOS for me so far), and Ubuntu with the `manpages-posix-dev` package

Comment: @EricRenouf Well, it explains what the OP observed, and it's consistent with the `man man` page on http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uman.htm. But if all *nix systems were identical, life would be too simple.

Comment: Perhaps so, though op behavior is also consistent with not having the posix pages installed, in which case I did not find this answer actually solved the problem on a couple of test systems I have

Comment: @Matthew I tried `man -e 1P grep`, `man -e 1p grep` and `man 1P grep` and `man 1p grep` eveything gives error 'No manual entry for grep'. Do we need to install something? Just fyi, i am using ubuntu 14.10. And `man -a grep` shows only the main grep man page. I believe something is missing on my machine.

Comment: @mtk if `man -a grep` shows only basic manual, then indeed it's missing. I'd go with Eric's suggestion to try installing additional manpages: `sudo apt-get install manpages-posix-dev`

Answer (score 1):

http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/MAN/ This is 1p man page for posix programmer

http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/grep/
This is for grep 1p man page

Comment: yes I can browse it on internet, but where do i see on my unix machine?